# Cartography and road maps in java

Tags: java, geolocation, routes, maps, cartography

Hi all
i'm developing an application must show a list of customers, resellers and other types of data an ao geographic map (from satellites) or on a road map for an university's exam.
With this application i've to calulate the isodromi distance and the street route, where possible, from a source and a destination.

I looked at Google Maps API but with the Google Maps Data API for Java i can only manipulare data like markers and i need an enterprise license for the integration in a non web application. And for Bing maps it's the same...

Can you recommend me a free library?, I don't mind if closed source,even if an open source would be better...

Thanks to every one in advance

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you should be looking into is spatial database mgt system. postgres extension like Postgis provides spatial features to it.

a spatial database allows you to perform spatial queries on your data, like calculating distance between geographic points... i don't know if this is what you are looking for, but it's worth a look, just a thought!

Comment: hi  and thanks for your replay. i'll google for some spatial database libraries. thanks again!